# Letting user access webpage if he has a certain role

Tags: php, laravel

I am making a small webpage with Laravel that has User and Admin roles.
My 'users' table consists of name, email, password and role value (0 for user, 1 for admin).

I dont need anything fancy so can I just make it so every time a normal user loads in a page that's meant for the administrator - he gets redirected?

To be more precise: How can I make it so whenever a new page loads, the users role gets checked and then my if or can statement checks if the users allowed to access the page?

For example I have a view:
results that displays all the match results(can be accessed by everyone) and I also have an admin/RESULTSadmin view, that should only be accessed by a user that has an admin role but the rest needs to get redirected. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Generally you'd check the role in the controller action and then act accordingly

Answer (score 0):

You can make parent controller with method which should check what you need and extend your controller from that (kind of old way but most simplest)

Another option make some middleware to check access

Also please take a look on laravel auth mechanism : https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/authentication#password-confirmation-protecting-routes